# React-Hook-Forms: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a form that accepts 5 values keyed in by the user. The sum of the first 4 values must match the 5th one.

```
valueA + valueB + valueC + valueD == valueE
```

If they don't, an error message pops up. The checking is in real-time and begins when the user keys in the value.

This is my code:

```
const {
        control,
        watch,
        getValues,
        setValue,
        setError,
        clearErrors,
        formState: { errors, isDirty },
    } = useForm({})


const watchValues= watch(["valueA", "valueB", "valueC", "valueD", "valueE"]);
    useEffect(() => {
        let val1 = getValues("valueA") ? parseFloat(getValues("valueA")) : 0.0;
        let val2 = getValues("valueB") ? parseFloat(getValues("valueB")) : 0.0;
        let val3 = getValues("valueC") ? parseFloat(getValues("valueC")) : 0.0;
        let val4 = getValues("valueD") ? parseFloat(getValues("valueD")) : 0.0;
        let val5 = getValues("valueE") ? parseFloat(getValues("valueE")) : 0.0;

        let compareValue = Boolean((val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 ).toFixed(2) === val5.toFixed(2));

        if (!compareValue) {
            setError("valueE", {
                type: "manual",
                message: "Error",
            });
        } else clearErrors("valueE");
    }, [watchValues]);
```

Before declaring `formState: { errors, isDirty },`, specifically `errors`, this was working as intended.
After adding `errors` to the `formState`, I started getting `Maximum update depth exceeded` issues.

I know why the error happens, but I can't see why would it happen here, what would cause the loop. I've only managed to pinpoint the issue to the `setError / clearError if-else` statement.

The end result I'm trying to reach is to stop the form from submitting **only** while the values do not match (so, if all fields are blank, that would be a valid input).

Comment: setError and clearError are modfing watchValues, this is because watch see those inputs as objects, including their error states and messages.

so, you can´t update a variable that is in the dependency array in the useEffect function.

Comment: how about setting useEffect dependencies with array destructuring like this: `[...watchValues]`

Comment: @SaeedShamloo initially tried building another ```useEffect``` to solve what @FelipeRodriguez  suggested. Then I tried your method and it works more or less the same. Why does that work?(Im still relatively new to React)

Comment: Your problem is that `watchValues` is an array and since Array is  considered an object in javascript, it's compering occurs by refrence equality check, so in every render you are creating a new array and react consider that `watchValues` has updayed, so `useEffect` executes executes on every render, and since you are calling  `clearError` or `setError` inside the useEffect actually you are updating the state and this cause rerender your componet, when rerender happens, again in the next render above scenario repeats

Answer (score 1):

try useWatch hook from react-hook-form , https://react-hook-form.com/api/usewatch.
It will help you with the re-rendering and also, put the result from it in the useEffect deps.

```
const watchValues = useWatch({control,});
useEffect(()=>{ ... what you have...}, [watchValues])
```